# sorting sections of text file content with ms-dos commands

Tags: windows, sorting, batch-file

I have a bunch of configuration files which I want to sort their content.  The file has sections in it, like the example below.
First, I need to sort the sections.  Then, I need to sort the lines in each section.

I am looking for some hints on how to do this automatically with batch of ms-dos commands.
What are the main steps?  Which commands to be used?
I will be grateful for your hints.
Thank you.

```
[DEF]  
ITY=YES  
WEKTY=NO  
WKEOW=50  
ADFGG=3  
SDF=YES  

[ABC]  
KASDF=AB  
WERY=59  
KAKSDOE=YES  
ABEE=NO  
PTOP=MAX  
WWQ=98  

...and so on
```

Comment: Welcome to StackoverFlow.  This is not a code writing service, please share any attempts you've made along with any error messages.

Comment: Yes, that's clear.  I wasn't expecting anyone to provide the codes.  I used the command SORT, but this sorts the whole content in the file, not within the sections.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows 10, but I want to make the batch file with ms-dos commands.

Comment: Unless you're running Windows 10 32-bit you don't have any old 16-bit MS-DOS commands installed on your machine. Even if you are running the 32-bit version of Windows you'd be better off using the faster and more powerful Windows commands to do this. Don't confuse the Windows command prompt with MS-DOS. MS-DOS is an old and very obsolete 16-bit operating system.